# How to calculate sum based on other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an account transaction table that lists all activities in the account.

```
id  qty  
1     100    
2     200     
3     -50     
4     20
```

The id column is an indecation of real time activities as `2` hapend after `1`, and `4` happened after `3`.

I need to add a column which per each row gives the current total sum:

```
id  qty    total_sum
1   100    100      / 0 + 100
2   200    300      / 100 + 200
3   -50    250      / 300 - 50
4    20     270      / 250 + 20
```

This is simple enough. However my table is huge, it contains very old rows which thier data isn't neccecry correct. To avoid it, I would like to calculate the sum from **buttom to top**, so that at least the newest records will have the currect values. In my case it is doable as for each user I always save the current updated total_sum for today... so I have a value to begin with.

In that case (`+` will be consider as `-` and `-` as `+` ) what I get is:

```
id  qty    total_sum
1   100    0      / 100 - 100
2   200    100 / 300 - 200
3   -50    300      / 250 + 50
4   20     250      / init_value - 20
```

The problem is that in each row `total_sum` present the sum before the action on the row was done. for example in row 2 it shows `total_sum=100` which is before the action of row 2 was proccessed.

How can I fix it to show the first total_sum column but calculated from buttom?

basicly what i need is:

```
id  qty    total_sum
1   100    100
2   200    300
3   -50    250
4   20     init_value (which is 270)
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT id,qty,(select init_value from x where .....)
    - Sum(a.qty)OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) as total_sum
FROM    a
ORDER  BY id ASC
```

How can I fix it? (Postgresql 9.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use LEAD/LAG function to access the next/previous quantity and use that in SUM.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f8e1/16)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table myt(
  id_ integer,
  qty_ integer
  );

insert into myt values(1,100);
insert into myt values(2,200);
insert into myt values(3,-50);
insert into myt values(4,20);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id_, qty_,
lead(qty_) over (order by id_) qty2
from myt
order by id_
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f8e1/16/0)**:

```
| id_ | qty_ |   qty2 |
|-----|------|--------|
|   1 |  100 |    200 |
|   2 |  200 |    -50 |
|   3 |  -50 |     20 |
|   4 |   20 | (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select id_, qty_,
270 - coalesce((sum(qty2) over (order by id_ desc)),0) total_sum
from (
  select id_, qty_,
  lead(qty_) over (order by id_) qty2
  from myt
) c
order by id_
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f8e1/16/1)**:

```
| id_ | qty_ | total_sum |
|-----|------|-----------|
|   1 |  100 |       100 |
|   2 |  200 |       300 |
|   3 |  -50 |       250 |
|   4 |   20 |       270 |
```